# sort a list based on references

Tags: java, sorting

I have list with the following structure:

```
Class Data {
   String id;
   String type;
   String reference;
}
```

The reference here may or may not be null.
I have the following set of data in a list:

```
[
{
id:"1",
type:"A",
reference:"3"
},
{
id:"2",
type:"B",
reference:null
},
{
id:"3",
type:"C",
reference:"1"
}
]
```

I want it be sorted based on reference - 1 references 3 and 3 references 1. Such items have to be grouped together as below:

```
[
{
id:"1",
type:"A",
reference:"3"
},
{
id:"3",
type:"C",
reference:"1"
},
{
id:"2",
type:"B",
reference:null
}
]
```

Comment: there are multiple solutions [based on the comparable interface, the comparator or a lambda as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784576/4014509).

Comment: `List<Data> list = ..; list.sort(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(d -> d.reference)));`

Comment: This isn't "sorting" by reference; it's creating a linked list based on the reference->id mapping, right? Can you give more example data?